# using entr to watch a directory without any matching files

Tags: bash, sed, citrix

I want to modify `*.ica` files (to launch Citrix apps) when they are downloaded (to add a transparent Key Passthrough option for remote desktop), so I settled on using `entr` to monitor the directory, and call then another script (which invokes `sed`) to update all `ica` files.

```
while true; do
  ls *.ica | entr -d  ~/Downloads/./transparentKeyPassthrough-CitrixIca.sh
done
```

However, this only works when there is already an `.ica` file in the directory.  If the directory has no `*.ica` files when first executed, `entr` errors with:

```
entr: No regular files to match
```

Putting a dummy `ica` file suffices, in which case the new (real) `ica` file  will be detected by entr, and then acted on.

Is there a better way to do this?

The alternative I can think of is to use `entr` to watch the whole directory for any changes, and if so, run `ls -l *.ica` and if the change resulted in a new `ica` file, and then in turn, run the above script.

It seems inelegant and complicated to nest `entr` that way, so wanted to know if there is some simple option I am missing.

Comment: maybe something like: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' | entr -d ...`

Comment: What if the directory initially contains one or more `*.ica` files, and then more are added later?  Would you then want to monitor the additional files, too?  In that case, monitoring the directory is a necessary behavior, not a work-around.  Right now you seem to be accomplishing that with your infinite `while` loop, but that is crude and incredibly inefficient.

Comment: If more `*.ica` files are added later, they are in fact acted on, which is exactly the functionality the `entr -d` option provides, and which I rely on when using the dummy `ica` file.

Comment: However after detecting one directory change, `entr` exits, which is the purpose of the `while` loop. It does in fact seem inefficient, but is the method  listed on the [entr's manpage](https://eradman.com/entrproject/).  My secondary script does selectively act on `ica` files, but I didn't want it to be invoked unnecessarily by other changes in the directory.

Comment: At my end `apt-cache show incron` says 'incron is an "inotify cron" system. It works like the regular cron but is driven by filesystem events instead of time events' -- [`https://github.com/ar-/incron`](https://github.com/ar-/incron).